# Why sleep mode connections are not reused by c3p0?

Tags: java, mysql, connection-pooling, c3p0

I develop an web application using Spring MVC + MySQL. To manage JDBC connection I used c3p0 for connection pooling.

If I am using c3p0, What I suppose if, 5 connections are open in pool and all 5 connections are in sleep mode and if I request `getConnection()` from java then one of them should be returned as `Connection`. Am I correct?

If Yes Then consider following load testing scenario where I am getting Exception `Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!`. Using `Jmeter` I started load test for 250 users in 15 seconds. I m continuously observing DB connections using `SHOE FULL PROCESSLIST` for first some minutes all is going well but as all the 250 users thrown to web server connections count is reached to 500 which is our `maxPoolSize`. So after this we are getting `Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!`.

At this point if I execute `SHOE FULL PROCESSLIST` then I can see all 500 connections are in sleep mode If I am correct in above statement that any *open connection that is in sleep mode will be returned by c3p0.* Then why I am getting this exception.?

Here is my c3p0 properties

```
MINPOOLSIZE=10
ACQUIREINCREMENT=1
MAXPOOLSIZE=500
INITIALPOOLSIZE=10
NUMBERHELPERTHREAD=100
MAXIDLETIME=10
MAXSTATEMENT=20
MAXSTATEMENTPERCONNECTION=5
IDLECONNECTIONTESTPERIOD=120
ACQUIRERETRYATTEMPT=10
ACQUIRERETRYDELAY=100
AUTOCOMMITONCLOSE=false
BREAKAFTERACQUIREFAILURE=false
TESTCONNECTIONONCHECKOUT=true
TESTCONNECTIONONCHECKIN=true
```

**Update**

I found this warning before `Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!` Exception

```
WARN : 30 Jun 2014 10:40:12.078 com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1839) - com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@e49561 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (10). Last acquisition attempt exception: 

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Too many connections
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1015)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4187)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4119)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:927)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1709)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1252)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2483)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2516)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2301)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor18.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:346)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:134)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:183)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:172)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:188)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1074)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1061)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1798)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:636)
WARN : 30 Jun 2014 10:40:12.078 com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.forceKillAcquires(BasicResourcePool.java:882) - Having failed to acquire a resource, com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@1035ff9 is interrupting all Threads waiting on a resource to check out. Will try again in response to new client requests.
```

Comment: Are your "users" actually multi-threaded? Why would you consider 250 users using 500 database connections as "going well"? That seems to indicate that connections are not being closed and returned to the pool.

Comment: I checked all my DB services connection is closed properly. I want to load test for concurrency means how concurrent users can sustain on specific configuration of server. So I started load test from 50 users in 10 sec then 100 users in 10 sec 150 users in 10 sec likewise..every time I observed that there is so many connections in sleep mode then also new connections are formed. Why sleep mode connections are not reused as c3p0 used for?

Comment: hi. those aren't c3p0 properties at all. c3p0 properties are case sensitive, and not all caps. if set via a c3p0.properties file, you'll need to prepend `c3p0.` to property names. if in a hibernate config, it's `hibernate.c3p0.` that you have to prepend. c3p0 dumps it's config @ INFO on pool init. check your logs to verify your config. however you mean to set up things, given your error it's likely `jdbcUrl`, `user`, or `password` that's amiss. in your logs you should find the stack trace of the Exception that provokes the one you are reporting. it may be more informative.

Comment: "Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!" has no relationship to `maxPoolSize`. the pool is reporting that it is trying and failing to acquire new/more Connections from the DBMS. at maxPoolSize, the pool ceases trying to acquire new Connections, except as old ones expire or fail away. you might be hitting DBMS limits to the number of Connections that can be held open. again, the Exception logged prior to the one you report would be more informative.

Comment: @SteveWaldman Yes I know this not exact properties of c3p0. I am setting this properties in an properties file and I am having an class through which I am calling getConnection() in that class I read all this properties and set to object of `ComboPooledDataSource` and the same file having dbURL,unam,password and other stuff.

Comment: @SteveWaldman Stack trace is added in question. I found `A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.` at the last of stack trace

Comment: @SteveWaldman as you said `you might be hitting DBMS limits to the number of Connections that can be held open` Yes in MySQL config file we set `max_connections` 500 is that the issue? I don't think so because I tried with increasing both upto 700 still I am getting same error when connections reached upto 700. My main question is connections that I can see in sleep mode is should be reused then why its not happening?

Comment: Nope. An Exception is logged by a separate Thread. You are looking at the Exception caught by your client, but that is indirectly triggered by an internal c3p0 Threads failure to acquire. note that, if the config you intend is set, you have dramatically increased the probability that a temporary network or db outage would provoke this condition, by setting acquireRetryAttempts to 10 (default is 30) and acquireRetryDelay to 100 (default is 1000).

Comment: hi... I'm on a mobile app... can't easily chat right now. :(

Comment: Ohh Okay, Sir I am not getting specially for line from ` note that, if the config you intend is set, you have dramatically increased...` can you explain in simple language.

Comment: You'll want to search your logs at WARNING for e.g. the following string "Acquisition Attempt Failed!!!" The last failed Exception in the round of acquisition attempts will be logged beneath that message. the logger's name will be `com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool`

Comment: Ohh In that case I have to set logger for wran level as currently its set for ERROR only. I will do that and get back. Thank You so much for your help on the Move :)

Comment: @SteveWaldman Sir, AS you said I updated question with warning log I found entry of warning saying "Acquisition Attempt Failed!!!" just above the exception.

Comment: @Amogh so the actual Exception that's triggering your failures is `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Too many connections`. It looks like you do need to increase the number of Connections your MySQL permits clients to keep open, or reduce maxPoolSize so that no more Connections are held than your DBMS configuration can support.

Comment: @SteveWaldman Sir, I increased the value of `ACQUIRERETRYATTEMPT` to 20 in my c3p0 config file and now its working fine, But I m having this problem when I go through tomcat log http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24487033/socketexception-in-tomcat7-error-log

Comment: Isn't a total of 500 open connections wildly high? Do you really expect to need this many?