# SocketException in tomcat7 error log

Tags: java, mysql, spring, tomcat7, c3p0

I found following warning in `tomcat7-stderr.{date}.log` file. My log file is filled with this log.

```
Mon Jun 30 12:27:47 GMT+05:30 2014 WARN: Caught while disconnecting...
** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.net.SocketException
MESSAGE: Socket is not connected

STACKTRACE:

java.net.SocketException: Socket is not connected
at java.net.Socket.shutdownInput(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.quit(MysqlIO.java:2261)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.realClose(ConnectionImpl.java:4697)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.close(ConnectionImpl.java:1630)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.close(NewPooledConnection.java:617)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.closeMaybeCheckedOut(NewPooledConnection.java:247)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.destroyResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:607)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1DestroyResourceTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1012)
at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:636)


** END NESTED EXCEPTION **
```

I searched a lot on net but no success. It seems about c3p0 connection pool. Why this Exception/Warn is logging? How to solve it?

Some extra information

- I am using c3p0 for connection pooling.
- I am connecting to MySQL server using named PIPE.

here is my c3p0 config.

```
MINPOOLSIZE=10
ACQUIREINCREMENT=1
MAXPOOLSIZE=500
INITIALPOOLSIZE=10
NUMBERHELPERTHREAD=100
MAXIDLETIME=10
MAXSTATEMENT=20
MAXSTATEMENTPERCONNECTION=5
IDLECONNECTIONTESTPERIOD=120
ACQUIRERETRYATTEMPT=10
ACQUIRERETRYDELAY=100
AUTOCOMMITONCLOSE=false
BREAKAFTERACQUIREFAILURE=false
TESTCONNECTIONONCHECKOUT=true
TESTCONNECTIONONCHECKIN=true
```

Comment: Could you paste your CP30 configuration please ?

Comment: @Pracede added in question.

Comment: I think this arrives when disconnecting..See the log "Mon Jun 30 12:27:47 GMT+05:30 2014 WARN: Caught while disconnecting..."

Comment: @Pracede Yes but what should I do to avoid this?

Comment: Could you post the log before the WARN ?

Answer (score 0):

Mysql forum had been decided that this bug as JVM bug. So, there will not be any fix from ConnectJ. Please check [here](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=62518) for further details. I believe, there is nothing much to do from your side.