# c3p0 maxIdleTime is same as wait_timeout of mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, database-connection, c3p0

I am having an Spring MVC + Mysql (JDBC 4) + c3p0 0.9.2 project.

In c3p0 `maxIdleTime` value is 240 (i.e 4 mins.) and `wait_timeout` in my.ini of Mysql to 30 seconds.

According to c3p0

> maxIdleTime:
>       (Default: 0)
>       Seconds a Connection can remain pooled but unused before being discarded. Zero means idle connections never expire.

According to Mysql

> wait_timeout: The number of seconds the server waits for activity on a
>   noninteractive connection before closing it.

Now i am having some douts on this:(some answers are known to me,Just wated to be sure I am correct or not)

1. unused connection means the connection which are in `sleep` state according to mysql(?)
2. What is interactive and noninteractive connections?
3. Is unused connections and noninteractive coonections are same? because my DBA set `wait_timeout` to 30 seconds (he come to this value by observing DB server so that very less amount of connections be in sleep mode) this means an connection can be in `sleep` mode for 30 seconds after that it will be closed but at the otherhand c3p0's `maxIdleTime` is set to 240 seconds so whats this `maxIdleTime` setting playing role in this case.
4. What is `interactive_timeout`?

Comment: The connections in sleep mode are most likely the inactive connections that are sitting in your pool. They should not be closed too quickly because having your pool recreate them upon the next request is costly. Why does your DBA suggest that the wait_timeout be set to 30 seconds?

Comment: @flup, Because while load testing I observed that `show full processlist` showing me `number of connections in DB=maxPoolSize` and I am continuously getting `Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!` exception. I posted this question Please Read More and one  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24451317/why-sleep-mode-coonections-are-not-reused-by-c3p0

Answer (score 30, accepted):

First Let's understand the mysql properties.

- `interactive_timeout` : interactive time out for mysql shell sessions
  in seconds like mysqldump or mysql command line tools. connections are in sleep state. Most of the time this is set to higher value because you don't want it to get disconnected while you are doing something on mysql cli.
- `wait_timeout`
  : the amount of seconds during inactivity that MySQL will wait before
  it will close a connection on a non-interactive connection in
  seconds. example: connected from java. connections are in sleep state.

Now let's understand c3po properties and it's relation with DB props.(I am just gonna copy from your question)

> - `maxIdleTime`: (Default: 0) Seconds a Connection can remain pooled but unused before being discarded. Zero means idle connections never
>     expire.

This refers to how long a connection object can be usable and will be available in pool. Once the timeout is over c3po will destroy it or recycle it.

Now the problem comes when you have `maxIdleTime` higher then the `wait_timeout`.
let's say if the `mxIdleTime : 50` secs and `wait_timeout : 40 s` then there is a chanse that you will get `Connection time out exception: Broken Pipe` if you try to do any operation in last 10 seconds. So `maxIdelTime` should always be less then `wait_timeout`.

Instead of maxIdleTime you can you the following properties.

- `idleConnectionTestPeriod` sets a limit to how long a connection will
  stay idle before testing it. Without `preferredTestQuery`, the default
  is `DatabaseMetaData.getTables()` - which is database agnostic, and
  although a relatively expensive call, is probably fine for a
  relatively small database. If you're paranoid about performance use a
  query specific to your database `(i.e. preferredTestQuery="SELECT 1")`
- `maxIdleTimeExcessConnections` will bring back the connectionCount back
  down to minPoolSize after a spike in activity.

Please note that any of the pool property(eg. `maxIdleTime`) only affects to **connection which are in pool** i.e if hibernate has acquired a connection and keeps it idle for than maxIdleTime and then tries to do any operation then you will get "Broken Pipe"

It is good to have lower `wait_timeout` on mysql but It's not always right when you have an application already built.
You have to make sure before reducing it that in your application you are not keeping connection open for more that `wait_time` out.

You also have to consider that acquiring a connection is expensive task and if have wait time out too low then it beats the whole purpose of having connection pool, as it will frequently try to acquire connections.

This is especially important when you are not doing connection management manually for example when you use Spring transnational API. Spring starts transaction when you enter an `@Transaction` annotated method so it acquires a connection from pool. If you are making any web service call or reading some file which will take more time than wait_time out then you will get exception.

I have faced this issue once.

In one of my projects I had a cron which would do order processing for customers. To make it faster I used batch processing. Now once I retrieve a batch of customers and do some processing(no db calls). When I try to save all the orders I used to get broken pipe exception. The problem was my wait_timeout was 1 minute and order processing was taking more time then that.  So We had to increase it to 2 minutes. I could have reduced the batch size but that was making the overall processing slower.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation, You cleared my points related to interactive_timeout,wait_timeout & maxIdleTime, but I did not get your last two bulleted points but no worries I will get understood eventually.

Comment: Will it okay to decrease `wait_timeout` up to 30/15 seconds so that no connection will be in sleep mode?

Comment: I have updated my answer. In brief you can reduce the wait_time out if you are sure that your application is not keeping connection for more than 30 seconds.

Comment: okay I m getting now, I posted this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24451317/why-sleep-mode-coonections-are-not-reused-by-c3p0 some days before can you please go through it and check. I will recommand you to read all the comments.

Comment: I checked the questions and comments. I just have one question why do you have maxIdleTime as 10 sec? What is you wait_timeout on mysql.

Comment: wait_timeout is 15 seconds.

Comment: change your config as below and change your wait time out to 60 seconds.  MINPOOLSIZE=10
ACQUIREINCREMENT=1
MAXPOOLSIZE=500
INITIALPOOLSIZE=10
MAXIDLETIME=50
ACQUIRERETRYATTEMPT=10
TESTCONNECTIONONCHECKIN=true and then try

Comment: Okay will do, but ACQUIRERETRYATTEMPT=10 is enough? Because Previously I changed 10 to 20. Then after this change my load test become successfull.

Comment: Yes, It's enough if you increase your time_out then same connection can be used multiple times and will reduce requirement of getting connection from database.

Comment: Ohh okay currently I am at home so can't load test by doing changes as you said. Tommaro I will do this once I m at workplace and will get back on this.Hope you understand.

Comment: I done Load test with the changes that you suggested last time. only 194 out of 200 users are successfully completed their jmeater scenario. Once I start my load test after 30-40 seconds I can see 500 (maxpool),So I am getting `Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database`. After 60 seconds (wait_timeout ) some connections are closing..

Comment: I am not getting one point which is described in question when MySQL having 500 connection some of them are in sleep mode then why c3p0 is using them?

Comment: Okay, I think there is something wrong with the application because it is not releasing connection once it is done using it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57093/discussion-between-amogh-and-amitchotaliya).

Comment: But I cross verified all my code to ensure that `connection.close()` is called after unite of work is done.

Comment: Hey,  unreturnedConnectionTimeout and debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces solved my problem I found one service where developer forget to call `close()` also I found some `Multiply prepared statement!` which is I am fixing now. Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57093/discussion-between-amogh-and-amitchotaliya)

Answer (score 0):

> unused connection means the connection which are in sleep state according to mysql(?)

According to mysql, this simply means that a connection was established with mysql/db, but there has been no activity here for the past amount of time and due to configuration / settings of mysql(which can be changed), the connection was destroyed.

> What is interactive and noninteractive connections?
>   Interactive connections are when your input hardware(keyboard) interacts using command line with mysql. In short where you write the queries

Non interactive or rather wait_timeout queries are those for which your code establishes connection with mysql.

> Is unused connections and noninteractive coonections are same? because my DBA set  wait_timeout to 30 seconds (he come to this value by observing DB server so that very less amount of connections be in sleep mode) this means an connection can be in sleep mode for 30 seconds after that it will be closed but at the otherhand c3p0's maxIdleTime is set to 240 seconds so whats this maxIdleTime setting playing role in this case.

MaxIdleTime is done by your code at hibernateJpa Configuration where you ask your code itself to close a hibernate connection(for example) after a connection is unused. You have ownership of this as a coder.

Wait_timeout on other hand is from mysql side. So it is upon the DB administrator to set it up and change.

> What is interactive_timeout?

Again, interactive timeout is when you are writing queries after connecting to mysql from keyboard on command line and that time conf in mysql gets up.

If you want to know more about how to change these values, go through this link:
http://www.serveridol.com/2012/04/13/mysql-interactive_timeout-vs-wait_timeout/

Hope now it is clear to you.:)