# SQLException: I/O Error: Read timed out

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, jdbc

I have a Java Spring application connecting to a SQL Server database.

The connection settings are:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl"
            value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://${db.host}:1433/TestDB" />
        <property name="user" value="${db.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${db.pass}" />

        <!-- these are connection pool properties for C3P0 -->
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="10" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="100" />
        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="5"/>
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="30000" />
    </bean>
```

everything works fine but sometimes I got the following error:

```
Could not open JDBC Connection for the transaction; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: Read timed out
```

I have searched a lot but can't find any clue, any idea or help?

I'm using

```
<bean id="sqlSession" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

in my `spring-config xml` to get my `sqlSession`, and in the DAO I use:

```
@Autowired  
SqlSession sqlSession;
```

and then I execute the queries I want. Is it possible that because the connection is not closed that this error exists?

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace. Also, are you sure `db.host` has the correct value, and that SQL Server is actually listening on port 1433 on that host?

Comment: Keep connection pool properties in server.xml. That is the right place for them.

Comment: @YatiSawhney OP is using spring, and it is perfectly acceptable to configure it in the spring config.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel sorry i don't have a copy of the stacktrace and this error didn't occurred again yet , and yes the values of  db.host and port number are correct because the error have occurred while the application was running already

Comment: In that case, this was likely just a network problem, or a connection killed because of inactivity. I don't think you need to worry about it. If it happens more frequently, you might want to reduce the `maxIdleTime` (the current value of 30000 seconds means a connection is allowed to be idle (unused) in the pool for over 8 hours, which is a bit much), and check timeout configuration on the server side.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel please see my edits in the code.

Answer (score 0):

In my case connections were getting dropped when the nightly db backup job triggered. I'm using jtds/sql-server as well. Here is what I did to fix it:

- Create/setup a health-check cron job that executes a simple query from within your application, like a short `select from`. Call it every 10 minutes or so and log the result. It will give you some feedback about when and why this is happening.
- Reduce the idle time parameter (maxIdleTime) in your configuration so that old connections get automatically discarded.

Keep in mind that if you don't change the maxIdleTime and you keep multiple connections open, some of them may remain in a bad state even if you are using the health-check function. Quoting from [c3p0 documentation](https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#managing_pool_size):

> By default, pools will never expire Connections. If you wish Connections to be expired over time in order to maintain "freshness", set maxIdleTime and/or maxConnectionAge. maxIdleTime defines how many seconds a Connection should be permitted to go unused before being culled from the pool. maxConnectionAge forces the pool to cull any Connections that were acquired from the database more than the set number of seconds in the past.

Another way to setup a health-check call is by using the [idleConnectionTestPeriod](https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_connection_testing) parameter. Also check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24656013/2079513) which can give you more ideas on how to set it up.